# laravel blade syntax for href="javascript:void(0);"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

Any one can tell me the right blade **syntax** for this `href="javascript:void(0);"`,i am using laravel 5.6.

Comment: Just Google it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Teams</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

its in my blade and its working for me